# Is there a Cocoa equivalent of map from C++?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, dictionary, nsdictionary

I really love map in C++, it's fast and easy to program.

Is there anything similar in Cocoa?

I know I can mix C++ and obj-c together, but I'd rather use a more obj-c way to program :)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [NSDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/) / [NSMutableDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/).

As an aside, you should use a map/dictionary when it's the best data structure choice, not just because it's easy and fast (although programmer time is expensive, proper structure choice will help create a better overall design). Maps make sense when you need to quickly look up values, and you don't care if they are stored in a sorted order.

Comment: map<>'s internal representation is sorted, and it allows you to iterate over the key-value pairs in sorted order. NSDictionary/NSMutableDictionary require extracting the keys and then sorting them to achieve the same end. I, too, am looking for an Obj-C analogue of map<>, but they aren't it.

Comment: @George: true, but that "ordering" comes as a cost. hash_map (or unordered_map) has faster lookups for known keys, and faster inserts and deletes. If you need a sorted associative container, then map<> makes sense, but otherwise hash_map is likely a better option.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to use NSMapTable. It's main benefit is that it won't copy the key the way NSDictionary does.

Comment: Also: NSHashTable (Mac only, not available on iOS AFAIK).